# Linking two projects

Tags: asp.net, vb.net

I am currently doing a project which is to be linked with another project. I.e., when
I click on some button in my current project's page I should get a page from the other project.. Can you suggest a way to do the same..

Comment: @Deviant, please explain why you have reverted my edit.

Answer (score 0):

You can always use `Response.Redirect()` to redirect the user to any internet available location.

If both your projects are configured as websites (i.e., they are accessible through virtual directories), then you can use this method to perform the redirection. Without more information, it is difficult to further troubleshoot any problems you may be facing with this simple procedure.

Note that you will not be able to share state information between the two applications (atleast not in a straightforward manner!)

Answer (score 0):

From the info you give in your question, I suppose you want to navigate from a 'module' in one project to a 'module' in another project, a page, or a control on a page...
A way to do this is to make the url to the modules configurable.
So you can navigate to the modules like this

```
Response.Redirect(ConfigurablePropertyName);
```

Or on the client like this:

```
<a href='<%= this.ConfigurablePropertyName %>' >Click me</a>
```

Hope this helps.